# Google search bug?

Tags: google-search

When I insert this URL in the browser's address field:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=notepad++.exe
```

then the plus characters are replaced by space characters in the Google search field:

[image]

How can this bug be avoided?

Comment: Special character Encoding in URLs is not a bug at all !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a bug - when encoding URLs, the character set becomes more limited, meaning that there needs to be a way to represent the full character set that is now unavailable.

- A plus (`+`) is used to mark a space - you will also see a space encoded as `%20`.
- A question mark (`?`) is often used to separate the resource path and the query string.
- A percent sign (`%`) is used to initiate the escape sequence.

If you want to make use of a literal `+` then you must escape it, using the standard `%xx` sequence, and providing the hex value for the character.

In this case, you want to represent a `+`, the [ASCII value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set) for which is `43` decimal, or `0x2B` hexadecimal.

#### This means that you need to use `%2B` in place of the `+`.

Similarly if you want to represent a literal `%`, then you must "*escape*" it, because it is used to initiate the escape sequence... you must use `%25` in place of a `%`.

---

Research "*URL Encoding*" to find out more

Try entering `notepad++.exe` into the box on this page: [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the '+'

fixed URL: https://www.google.de/search?q=notepad%2B%2B.exe

Some characters arent supported or have a specific purpose in URLs thus you cant just put them in where ever you want. You can get around that problem by escaping them like this:

%[insert hexadecimal representation of the character]

Answer (score 1):

> How can this bug be avoided?

It actually isn't a bug.

However, you can use `notepad%2B%2B++.exe`, instead to get around the intentional behavior.